# Union of 2 convex sets

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n→ \mathbb{R}_∞$ be convex over the sets A, B which are also convex.

$A ∩ B = ∅$ and $A ∪ B$ is convex.

Then is $f$ is convex on $A ∪ B$?  Why or why not?

I am confused particularly by the meaning of a function being convex on a set.

My intuition tells me that $f$ is indeed convex on $A \cup B$ but I can't put my thoughts down on paper in writing.

Answer (score 3):

$A=[0,1]$ and $B=(1,2]$ are convex.
$f(x)=0$ for $x \neq 1$ and $ f(1)=1$. What do you think of this case?

Comment: Oh,so it isn't convex over $A \cup B$ then. Your post has helped me consider functions and sets in a simpler light, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! An interesting element to remember about real convex functions is that those are not always continuous at the boundaries of their interval of definition.

Comment: would you be able to recommend any texts on convex analysis? Particularly something that has a section on subdifferentials and halflines/hyperplanes ?

Comment: On this topic, most of the good book I have are in French. But I'm sure that other members of the blog will be able to recommend good English books.